# Core Data fetch by property count

Tags: core-data, ios4

I'm trying to fetch just objects that has a nsset inside bigger then 0 in core data
Something like

> fetch all objects that object.set > 0

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a way that works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"set.@count > 0"];
```

If there's a better way, please let me know, I'm posting here to help anyone that has the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: +1 That's your best solution. The collection operators are intended for just such task.